# Create difference table depends on slicer or filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables `Table1`, `Table2` and two filters `Year1`, `Year2` in Power BI report. I am filtering `Table1` depending on `Year1`, `Table2` depending on `Year2`. I want to create `Table3` which shows the difference between `Table1` and `Table2` after applying filters(`Year1` and `Year2`).

```
Table1:
Brand Amount Year
ABC   1000   2017
ABC   2000   2018

Table2:
Brand Amount Year
ABC   1000   2017
ABC   2000   2018
```

Filters contain years. If I select `2017` in `Year1` then `Table1` will show

```
ABC 1000  2017
```

If I select `2018` in `Year2` then `Table2` will show

```
ABC  2000  2018
```

I want `Table3` which shows a difference that is

```
ABC  1000
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is in two separate underlying tables you should be able to simply use a calculated column:

```
TableDiff = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Amount])-SUM(Table2[Amount]))
```

If however you are talking about the "Table" visual in Power BI, and you have two table visuals pulling from the same source, I don't believe there is a way to reference the actual data contained in a Power BI visual. You could create a duplicate table in your model and use the above formula, however depending on the size of your data this may not be feasible.